# Import CSV Files in Multiple Access Tables

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have csv files in a folder that look like this:

```
BAS09012018_1.csv
BAS09012018_2.csv
BAS09012018_3.csv
BAS09012018_4.csv
BAS09012018_5.csv
```

I want to import them into 5 different Access Tables based on title ("BAS") and Number (1,2 3, etc)

Here is the code I have. When I run it no data is transferred. The Import Specification is correct because I was able to import the csv file manually.

```
HasFieldNames = False

dir_List = "C:\Users\LVWis\dump\UnzippedFiles\"
Directory = Dir(Dir_List)

    If Len(Directory) > 0 Then

    Do
    FileName = "C:\Users\LVWis\dump\UnzippedFiles\" & Directory
    endFileName = Right(Trim(FileName), 5)
    beginFileName = Left(Trim(FileName), 3)

    If endFileName = "1.csv" And beginFileName = "BAS" Then
    strTable = "BAS_1"
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "BAS_1a", strTable, FileName, HasFieldNames
    strPathFile = Dir()

    ElseIf endFileName = "2.csv" And beginFileName = "BAS" Then
    strTable = "BAS_2"
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "BAS_2a", strTable, FileName, HasFieldNames
    strPathFile = Dir()

    ElseIf endFileName = "3.csv" And beginFileName = "BAS" Then
    strTable = "BAS_3"
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "BAS_3a", strTable, FileName, HasFieldNames
    strPathFile = Dir()

    ElseIf endFileName = "4.csv" And beginFileName = "BAS" Then
    strTable = "BAS_4"
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "BAS_4a", strTable, FileName, HasFieldNames
    strPathFile = Dir()

    ElseIf endFileName = "5.csv" And beginFileName = "BAS" Then
    strTable = "BAS_5"
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "BAS_5a", strTable, FileName, HasFieldNames
    strPathFile = Dir()

    End If

    Directory = Dir
    Loop Until Len(Directory) = 0

    End If
```

Comment: You should test your code by checking the contents of your variables, f.i. by using message boxes. Assuming you did define variables as your code doesn't tell.

Comment: Step into the code to see if something is being missed.